# Google Geocoder GlsClient status codes

Tags: android, geocoding

I have been successfully using the Google Geocoder using the following code:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(search, 5);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
...
}
```

Recently it stopped returning any results even with something like "Paris, France". It does not throw any exceptions, but outputs a failure in LogCat:

```
07-09 12:05:06.555: W/GlsClient(720): forwardGeocode(): GLS failed with status 5
```

I have been searching for any documentation listing possible failure status codes but the Geocoder API documentation does not list them and there does not seem to be any documentation for "GlsClient".

Could anyone kindly point me in the right direction?